# developing apps scripts on the local machine(IDE), non in the google web interface

Tags: google-apps-script

Today I've found an interesting thing in GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT :) But their own web interface is not comfortable for me - is the any way to keep and edit scripts on the local machine and then upload to google ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [Eclipse plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script) for writing not running. Leave a comment if you try it.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. As I've understood from manuals to access code for editing there is a need to get files with RESTful interface of Google Drive API. I think Eclipse plugin runs this way. Sublime text plugin does the same, but only version 2. also there is a way to manage sources via Cloud SDK, but I've got errors .... I'm in progress ... :) Thank you!:)